# Vue native color picker @input when no change is made

Tags: vue.js, color-picker

Here's a situation: I have a regular non-Vue component color picker with the simple `<input type="color"/>` which works almost perfect, except in one case. The case being, when there's already a color existing in the picker and all the user does is click "Ok". I would expect that the vue @input or @change event would fire and set the color value even if the user didn't choose a *different* color. However, when the user simply clicks "Ok" and does not choose a new color, there is no event fired for either @change or @input. What's a way to fire this event in such a case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That functionality is unfortunately not available.

You can use `@focus`, with the caveat that it will fire when you click, and when you exit (cancel or OK)

You could add some custom @blur and @focus events to get something similar, but I think using just @focus (triggered on click too) may work in most scenarios

Comment: Unfortunately it also fires when they simply tab into the input too. I've just made a redundant \@click and \@input so it may change the color twice but at least this way it always does my coloring even if when it's first clicked it will use whatever color is there initially and then use the new color if they chose a different one.